# How to get and set last 3 values from ArrayList into TextViews?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an app contain four Text View say a,b,c and I have an array list from which I have to get last four index items and set that items in these `Textview`.

How do I do that?

*Let suppose i have 4 array like :- "1","2","3","4" then I have to get 1,2 and 3  not last value and set in `Textview`.*

code

```
 List<CProduct> list = new ArrayList<CProduct>();
    list.add(new CProduct("Coca-Cola"));
    list.add(new CProduct("Mountain Dew"));
    list.add(new CProduct("Denver Dew"));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Index:::" + i);
        CProduct p = list.get(i-1);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a reverse loop

```
List<CProduct> list = new ArrayList<CProduct>();
list.add(new CProduct("Coca-Cola"));
list.add(new CProduct("Mountain Dew"));
list.add(new CProduct("Denver Dew"));

for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= list.size()-3; i--) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Index:::" + i);
    CProduct p = list.get(i);

}
```

Comment: Check this aanswer .

Comment: i should be i = list.size()-1

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
List<CProduct> list = new ArrayList<CProduct>();
    list.add(new CProduct("Coca-Cola"));
    list.add(new CProduct("Mountain Dew"));
    list.add(new CProduct("Denver Dew"));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Index:::" + i);
        CProduct p = list.get(i);

    }
```

Comment: i have to set each value in three different textviews

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    tv[i].setText(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: i have to set in three different textviews

Comment: You can add arraylist TextView []tv=new TextView[3];

Comment: I have three different Textview with different id's

Comment: tv[0]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[1]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[2]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);

Comment: and also what ever length of arraylist whether it increase at run time i only want to set last 3 index value in textview